# Why Java throw java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException when I invoke wait() in static way synchronized block?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I do not understand why Java throw exception from subject in this code. Could somebody explain me it?

```
class Wait implements Runnable
{
    public void run() {
        synchronized (Object.class) {
            try {
                while(true) {
                    System.out.println("Before wait()");
                    wait();
                    System.out.println("After wait()");
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

public class ObjectMethodInConcurency 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Wait w = new Wait();
        (new Thread(w)).start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Read the javadoc for `wait()`.

Comment: @nos `The current thread must own this object's monitor.` and `Throws:IllegalMonitorStateException - if the current thread is not the owner of the object's monitor.`

Comment: You can only call `wait()` on an object which you have synchronized on.  You are calling `this.wait()`, so instead of `synchronized (Object.class)`, you must do `synchronized (this)`.  Object.class is not your object, it is a java.lang.Class object created by the Java runtime.

Comment: You are not calling notify() anywhere.

Comment: Thank you for information. I changed method call on `Object.class.wait()` and it works like I want.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use **synchronized (this) {** instead of  **synchronized (Object.class)** in your class

**EDIT**

**Reasoning behind the IllegalMonitorException in above code**

In Java using synchronized keyword is a way to create and obtain a monitor object which will be used as lock to execute corresponding code block.

In the above code that monitor is "Object.class".

And wait() method tells the current thread to wait until it is notifyed and you have to invoke wait() on the monitor object which owns the lock.

So the way to invoke wait() method is like below otherwise you will get IllegalMonitorException.

```
synchronized(monitor){
    monitor.wait();
}
```

So for your example you can either use `"Object.class.wait()"` or change the monitor to `this` since you are calling `wait()` method on the current instance

Comment: Because method call is on `this`. Method like wait, notify have to be invoke on synchronized object.

Comment: @Gray - Added my understanding about why it is giving IllegalMonitorException

Comment: You certainly did.  Looks great.  +1  One of the things to always realize with SO is that are you answering also for posterity.